# SQL JOB Output File - Remove Header

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a job that outputs the data into a file for manipulation later. I can easily output the file In the Job Type I have it set up for T-SQL for my query and this is the advanced tab for the Job step.

[image]

It's working fine, except for the data that is being exported is coming out with a header, any ideas how I can get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: T-SQL is the SQL dialect used with SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Sorry about that, Fixed :)

Comment: Using this interface you cannot - this is outputting log files, not just your query data. If you want to output pure data files you need to investigate export processes such as SSIS, the bcp.exe command line tool, PowerShell, etc., all of which can be launched from SQL Agent jobs but would be exporting data into a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AlwaysLearning for pointing me in the right direction, went with the PowerShell solution

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd
```

Thanks again!!